# If it is possible to use Composer test unit on two networks with getNative().invokeChaincode()?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

There is one network in my program that it need to `'invoke'` another networks `'transaction'`,I want to write a test unit before deploy to the real enviroment.  Is it possible?
In my opinion, I want to use the `getNative().invokeChaincode` function, but I have no idea get the `'channel'` parameter in the test unit, is there any way to solve it?
If it is possible to start two networks in one test.js? 
I declared two 'AdminConnection' with different __dirname, but it arise an error which is

```
Error: No network administrators or bootstrap transactions are specified
```

in the process of

```
const anotherAdminCards = await anotherAdminConnection.start(anotherBND.getName(), anotherBND.getVersion(), startOptions);
```

I have modified the `BusinessNetworkDefinition's` path

Comment: If you plan to drive your unit test as a standalone local run (say using npm test) using the embedded connector then you will have to mock the call the getNativeAPI as it will throw an Error when run inside the embedded runtime

Comment: Do you mean that getNative() can't get invokeChaincode() ? Is there any good suggestion If I want to test the interaction between two networks? I declared two 'AdminConnection' in one test.js, and change the __dirname which pointed to another directory,and I want to start to networks in one test.js, and invoke one network's function from another. But it arise an error which is 'Error: No network administrators or bootstrap transactions are specified'

Comment: When run in the embedded runtime (which would be used for unit testing) then getNativeAPI will through an error. When run inside a real fabric getNativeAPI will return you the stub object so you can call native fabric apis. So you would either have to stub and simulate the getNativeAPI call yourself, or run it inside a real fabric

Comment: Ok.But How Can I use getNativeAPI() to invoke other network functions?Is there any examples? I have ask another question. Can you help me to solve it? the url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397342/cant-start-network-with-function-of-http-or-getnative-invokechaincode-in-wi

Comment: see the tutorial here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network for an example on how to invoke other chaincode

Comment: I have learned the tutorial, but I did't find any function like 'getResourceInRegistry()', If I need to invoke a function in other network, how can I set the input parameter? For example, if there is a  functionA() in the network's logic.js, and I can call this funcionA() with 'composer-rest-api', the request body is a json, so if I can  use getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode() in the same way?I don't know how to set the Second parameter (paramter array) of getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode().